# PHP Regex validate URL between homepage or innerpage

Tags: php

I want to validate multiple URLS to check whether its a home page/domain name or a inner page/full path URL but my code only validates the string without `http` or `https` please update me what I am doing wrong in it.

PHP Code

```
    $urls = [
        "http://example.com",
        "https://www.example.net",
        "http://example.com/page.html?a=123",
        "http://example.com/page?a=123",
        "http://example.com/",
        "https://example.net/",
        "example.com",
        "demo.example.net"
    ];
foreach ( $urls as $url) {
    if ( preg_match('/^(?!\-)(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d\-]{0,61})?[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,63}$/', $url)) {
        echo "$urls is domain";
    } else {
        echo "$url is full URL";
    }
}
```

Expected Results

```
http://example.com (domain)
https://www.example.net (domain)
http://example.com/page.html?a=123 (full URL)
http://example.com/page?a=123 (full URL)
http://example.com/ (domain)
https://example.net/ (domain)
example.com (domain)
demo.example.net (domain)
```

Comment: I'd probably just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php, and draw my conclusions from whether the `path` is longer than 1 character, and `query` is empty ...

Comment: Yes that will be the option but sometime users don't pur http or https so I want to stick it with regex do you have any solution for it?